# What will be the value of $\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos 2x}}{x}$

Tags: functions

I expanded th term to get
$\frac{\sqrt{2\sin^2 x}}{x}$
Help me proceed further.

Comment: As such the question doesn't make much sense. The value of $(1-\cos2x)^{1/2}/x$ is $(1-\cos2x)^{1/2}/x$.

Comment: Any particular $x$? Is the question supposed to be about a limit?

Comment: Do you mean to study the limit for $x \to 0$? As it is now, the question is meaningless and will probably get closed.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos 2x}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{2\sin^2 x}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x}\lvert\sin x\rvert$$

Comment: Why is it mod of x?

Comment: Sorry, Mod of sinx

Comment: sorry, I don't know what do you mean?

Comment: By the way, you can remove that ugly space between the first bar and the s by using \! just after the bar, like this: $|\!\sin x|$.

Comment: @A---B Basically, we wont get anything negative out of under root?

Comment: Is this why we use mod?

Comment: @Drishtinarula No. It is because $(x^2)^{1/2}=x$ or $−x$ but we know that a function can't have two images for a pre-image. So when we define $f(x) =  \sqrt{x}$ we define it as $f : \mathbb{R}^+ \cup {0} \to  \mathbb{R}^+ \cup {0}$, thus we write $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, since we need only +ve square root of x , not the negative one.

Comment: @PhilippeMalot Better yet: `$\lvert\sin x\rvert$` gives $\lvert\sin x\rvert$. In LaTeX it's recommended to use `amsmath` that provides these two commands and also `\lVert` and `\rVert` for the double bars.

Answer (score 0):

$$1-\cos2x=1-(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)=1-\cos^2x+\sin^2x=\sin^2x+\sin^2x=2\sin^2x\implies$$

$$\frac{(1-\cos2x)^{1/2}}x=\frac{\sqrt2\,\sin x}x$$

In the above we assume, of course, the corresponding quantities that are under square root are non-negative. Thus, $\;\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\sqrt{\sin^2x}=\sin x\;$ if $\;0\le x\le\pi\;\pmod{2\pi}\;$ , and etc.

Comment: For all real number $x$, $(x^2)^{1/2}=|x|$.

Comment: "$\sqrt{\sin^2x}=\sin x$" hurts.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the mathematical corrections (who knows what "left side" you meant, though) . The rest you can keep to yourself. Really.

Comment: To err is human! DonAntonio, for some reason, you don't seem to see the error in your message: you wrote $\sqrt{\sin x}$ in place of $\sqrt{\sin^2 x}$.

Comment: @PhilippeMalot Because nobody **before** told me. Now that you made evident the obvious typo it is corrected now. Oh, I am so human...:)

Comment: @egreg Oh, my! A downvote...I hope I'll be able to survive...And you mention, btw, something I can't see in my answer.

Comment: @egreg Your concern about future readers is really moving. It was only until Phillipe pointed the typo that I saw it. There are pretty many left and right sides there. And the answer isn't wrong. Oh, and other thing: my answer was almost two minutes **before** E.H.E.'s . Just a matter of being accurate, to avoid...oy, yes: silliness. ;)

Comment: @egreg And that's why I wrote, after my attention was called on the square root thing, that the equality is true for $\;0\le x\le \pi\;$, just as in your example you could write that $\;3x-1=2x+2\;\;\text{whenever}\;\;3\le x\le3 \;$ ...

Comment: @egreg It really doesn't matter: this or that way, with these or those restrictions. I didn't, and I won't write that because EHE already did. I tried to develop a little more, missed that little thing (never said otherwise) and then corrected a little typo. That's all. It seems like you're seeing here an awfully big mistake. It is not, **and it was not**, such . If you want, call it "a more restricted, or an uglier" answer, or whatever. Now, let it go, dude. Saluti.

Comment: (Note: I removed my previous comments.) This answer is correct as long as one assumes, somewhat arbitrarily, that $0\le x\le\pi$ (modulo $2\pi$). There is no reason whatsoever for adding that limitation. Since fixing the answer to allow for complete generality is easy (and is already in an other answer), I issued a downvote.

Comment: Good. The downvote is there and it is fine for me. I stopped caring about downvotes/upvotes since it is futile: the site allows to downvote without any explanation, in spite of severat tens (that I know of) of member complaining for that. So be it. It is not like we're going to be richer, smarter, prettier or whatever because of less or more points. Enjoy and thanks for at least explaining your rationale for downvoting.